# how to resize the font of "No Options"?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Autocomplete from material-ui and trying to make the font size of "No Options" to be aligned with other fonts. I have tried to use styled component to set the font size but it didn't work. Is there a way to resize it smaller? Thank you

[Here is how it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGycC.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style "No Options" with class name `MuiAutocomplete-noOptions`;

```
.MuiAutocomplete-noOptions {
   font-size: 16px;
   // 
}
```

From Mui Autocomplete documentation:
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete

`noOptions  .MuiAutocomplete-noOptions  Styles applied to the no option wrapper.`